# Python3, subprocess.Popen with shell argument work reversely

Tags: python

I encounter a question that:

```
call subprocess.Popen('adb shell ls', shell=True)  # has NO console output

call subprocess.Popen('adb shell ls', shell=False) # has console output
```

The results are reversely as I studied.

Any one know what happen that the shell argument?
Thanks!!

env: on 64-bit Python 3.6 on a 64 bit Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: 
From docstring: "shell: If true, the command will be executed through the shell."

"shell" argument is not handle console output. it’s say if the command (first argument) is type of “shell” / “bash” / etc, similar to “#!/bin/bash” define as first line on script files.

There are several options to get executed process output with “subprocess”:

1. Read output from process object, “stdout” file type member  - By using stdout=subprocess.PIPE:

> ```
> In [2]: proc = subprocess.Popen("ls /tmp/dir1", shell=True, 
>             stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
> In [3]: proc.poll()
> Out[3]: 0
> In [4]: proc.stdout
> Out[4]: <open file '<fdopen>', mode 'rb' at 0x105e06f60>
> In [5]: print proc.stdout.read()
> file1
> file2
> output1
> ```

2. Read output from your own file type object - By pass your own file object for STDOUT:

> ```
> In [6]: with open("/tmp/dir1/output1", "wt") as stdout_file:
>    ...:     proc = subprocess.Popen("ls /tmp/dir1", shell=True, stdout=stdout_file, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
>    ...:     while proc.poll() is None:
>    ...:         pass
>    ...:     
>
> In [7]: with open("/tmp/dir1/output1", "rt") as stdout_file:
>    ...:     print stdout_file.read()
>    ...:     
> file1
> file2
> output1
> ```

3. Use default “stdout” - Similar to output on “os.system” - to console. (Probably what your’e looking for)

> ```
> In [8]: proc = subprocess.Popen("ls /tmp/dir1", shell=True)
>
> In [9]: file1 file2   output1
> ```

See docstring for more options.